# Problemas con un bot para facebook [Google Apps Script]

Tags: javascript, arraylist, google-apps-script, ordenamiento, random

Este robot puede usarse para varios usuarios donde comparten un link y un mensaje a diferentes destinos como a una fanpage, un grupos, perfiles de amigos, etc.

Dentro de las variables del robot se configura cada uno de los tokens de acceso de los usuarios en el array **acceso** también los links en el array **enlace** el ID y nombre donde se va a publicar en el array **destino** y los mensajes en el array **estado**

La función **mezclar()** es justamente la encargada de sortear de manera aleatoria un elemento de la lista de los arrays. Esta función es secundaria ya que luego es utilizada por la función principal **compartir()** para colectar todos los datos sorteado y armar el enlace final a ejecutar

```
var robot={

acceso:[
{usuario:"xxxxxxx",token:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},
{usuario:"xxxxxxx",token:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},
{usuario:"xxxxxxx",token:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},
{usuario:"xxxxxxx",token:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
],

enlace:[
{link:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},
{link:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},
{link:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},
{link:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
], 

destino:[
{nombre:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",id:"123456789"},
{nombre:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",id:"123456789"},
{nombre:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",id:"123456789"},
{nombre:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",id:"123456789"}
],

estado:[
{mensaje:"mensaje 1"},
{mensaje:"mensaje 2"},
{mensaje:"mensaje 3"},
{mensaje:"mensaje 4"}
]
};

function mezlar(alazar){
var a=alazar.sort(function(){return 0.5-Math.random()});
a.reverse();
a=a.sort(function(){return 0.5-Math.random()});
return a;
}

function compartir(){

var a=mezlar(robot.destino);robot.idsorteado=a[0].id;
var b=mezlar(robot.estado);robot.mensajesorteado=b[0].mensaje;
var c=mezlar(robot.enlace);robot.linksorteado=c[0].link;
var d=mezlar(robot.acceso);robot.tokensorteado=d[0].token;

UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/"+robot.idsorteado+"/feed",{
muteHttpExceptions:true,
method:"post",
payload:{
method:"post",
message:robot.mensajesorteado,
link:robot.linksorteado,
access_token:robot.tokensorteado
}
});
}
```

**Mi pregunta es ...**

Como puedo modificar la función **mezclar()** para que en vez de seleccionar los valores de manera random en los arrays, los seleccione en el orden en el que están o por el índice que están ubicados

por ejemplo la primera vez que se ejecute **compartir()** se colecten los datos de los primeros valores, luego al ejecutar nuevamente **compartir()** seleccione los segundos valores y así sucesivamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En la pregunta has definido lo que  esa función hace: *mezclar de forma aleatoria*, entonces me pregunto si no deberías crear otra función que haga lo que quieres: tomar los valores tal cual en el array. El punto crucial sería guardar un registro para saber qué valores ya fueron enviados y no enviarlos de nuevo. Hay mil formas de hacerlo y todo depende de tu contexto. Por ejemplo, entre las posibilidades que existe: a) Se podrían eliminar del array una vez enviados, b) Se podría tener en el array una bandera por cada valor con `true`o `false` o con `0` o `1` para saber cuáles fueron enviados

Comment: c) Se podría tener un array auxiliar donde se guardan los que fueron enviados y comparar contra ese array auxiliar ... etc, etc, etc. Como ves, hay mil formas de hacer una misma cosa. Lo principal aquí es que muestres lo que has intentado y nos digas qué problemas concretos tienes, porque como ves, primero hay que definir lo que necesitas, en base al uso posterior que tendrán esos datos en tu Aplicación. Además, si la función no va a *mezclar* datos, no deberías llamarla *mezclar*. El aspecto *nominativo* es importante, para no perderse en el código.

Comment: La idea es que entre ejecución y ejecución valla obteniendo los elementos uno a uno tal cual se encuentran indexados en la lista de array, de algún modo también debo crear una función que recuerde cual fue el último elemento seleccionado para que cuando se llame nuevamente se entregue el siguiente . Muchas gracias por su respuesta me ayudo o orientarme saludos